# Is parslet or treetop good choice to create a simple DSL?

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

I'm playing around with the idea of creating a simple DSL for creating some test data against an API. Let's say that this API has Unicycles, Wheels, and Seats.

I'd like to write:

```
show unicycle # lists all unicycles
new unicycle # creates a new unicycle, assumes a new wheel needs creation
new unicycle with new wheel # more explicit version of the above
new unicycle with wheel 123 # new unicycle using a specific wheel
```

Same idea goes for Seats and so on. Underneath this would map to some very simple CRUD calls. Is it overkill to use treetop, parslet, citrus, etc for a job like this? Is it easier just to do some regex parsing? Or is there another alternative?

Comment: What did you end up using?

Comment: @gymbrall unfortunately I had to put the project on hold as it was just a side thing. But I'm probably going to try parslet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a few simple and few complex parsers with treetop and I like it. I know almost nothing about Parslet. Aside from the fact that you have to spend the time to learn how to use it, I don't see much of a downside to using Treetop for the type of purpose you've described. I'd say with just using regexes by themselves, you'll end up building a lot of the structure that Treetop already provides within its framework.

One alternative that comes to mind: depending on how simple the complete grammar for the statements you want to create are and if you aren't necessarily wedded to natural language, you could probably implement the functionality of what you've shown so far very easily with [Thor](http://whatisthor.com/).

Let me know if you have any other questions.